# APC on Windows makes server terminate connection

Tags: php, apc

I have a slight problem and cannot for the life of me figure out what is happening. I am running a Linux machine on a server with APC enabled. Everything works fine.

Now when I enable APC on Windows the server starts terminating the connection. You know, the "Site currently unavailable" message Firefox spits out.

I tried the access logs, error logs and there is nothing there to indicate an error. How could APC influence on a server like this?

BTW: I have a CMS on my local server/live server. On the live server it works great with APC. On the dev server the connection terminates. The strange thing is, simpler scripts execute just fine. The CMS is using CakePHP.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried the access logs, error logs and there is nothing there to indicate an error.

This is not very helpful - did you check to see if the request is logged at all?

Is every request to the webserver affected? Just the PHP scripts? All the PHP scripts?

My guess would be that you have the wrong version of APC installed or have loaded it along with another opcode cache (e.g. Zend optimizer)

C.

Comment: The request is not logged at all. No, not every request is affected. Just PHP scripts. Not even all the PHP scripts, small ones are not affected.

It seems the only affected scripts are the ones using CakePHP, which seems very odd to me. I have no other opcode cache on this machine, not that I know of at least.

I have APC version 3.0.19 installed.